# jQuery security, execute code in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, firebug, embed

I would like to know if embed js is a problem for site security, i mean, if i have an input text and i need to manipulate what the user inputs inside, if i put `'<script> alert('hey');</script>'` inside text input, cause of manipulation, it is executed in the browser but then in my server side script i remove all not-secure tags from that string, so i think i will have no problems in server-side, but what about browser side?

if malicious embeds something like `$(document).load(some malicious script);` will be a problem in browser-side? this is maybe a banal question i know but i ever asked to me this fact, if for example in firebug i embed `$(somenthing).load(somenthing)` just for example, can be this a security problem?

hope my question is clear, sorry for my bad english :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, it is a major security problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: so anyone is XSS vulnerable cause of jquery $().load() + firebug ? :O

Comment: @lspuk, no. You are vulnerable if you echo back verbatim something that someone enters on your site. Just because someone types something into an input box doesn't mean that what they type there is necessarily ever executed.

Comment: No one is vulnerable "because" of jQuery.  Remember, at its core, jQuery is just a convenience library.  It wraps native browser functions in a consistent way.  [Most jQuery 'bugs' people find are actually bugs in their own code.](http://docs.jquery.com/How_to_Report_Bugs#Make_sure_it_is_a_jQuery_bug)  Yes, Firebug (or Chrome's or IE's Dev Tools) allows a user to inject arbitrary script into any document.  However, someone doing that is clever enough to use the console in the first place.  This brings us back to the basic rule of web development: **never trust client input.**

Comment: @josh3736 please read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

You want to read up on [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (and [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)). If you *encode* all the HTML parts that could launch script (see the [OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)) tags, you will be fine; when the string is returned to the client there won't be any scripts left to execute. If any script remains, however, and it's returned to the client, the potential for sadness remains.

Comment: stop :P, maybe i wrote bad and i'm sorry if is. I'm not talking about server-side :P i mean browser-side :P

Comment: Removing all script tags might not be good enough.  If he uses any user input at all he may be vulnerable- for example, the string `javascript:alert('xss')` can be inputted for an href, allowing xss.  This is especially true if he is using user submitted content (i.e. links) as the url parameter for .load.